Can batch normalization be implemented for Transformer model
So I'm fresher in ML field and I have been assigned a task to implement batch normalization for MarianMT model without using any other hyperparameters. So how can i proceed with the task. I know about layer normalization but for batch normalization i'm not sure about how to implement. Can someone help me with this.
Custom training loop with batch normalization
def __init__(self, model):
    super(CustomMarianMTModel, self).__init__()
    self.model = model
    self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm1d(model.config.d_model)

def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels):
    outputs = self.model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
    logits = outputs.logits
    logits = logits.transpose(1, 2)  # Transpose for batch normalization
    logits = self.batch_norm(logits)
    logits = logits.transpose(1, 2)  # Transpose back to original shape
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)), labels.view(-1))
    return loss

